# Error in GEE reduction : Output of image computation is too large (19 bands ...)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using Random Forest for classification, when i wish to compute the area of each class, i have this error: Output of image computation is too large (19 bands ...),
but i think i have only one band in the classification result, i use 19 bands for the classification.

this is the code:

```
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(500).train({ //200
features: training,
classProperty: 'class',
inputProperties: finalbands
});

var classified = objects_mean.select(finalbands).classify(classifier);

var areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000).addBands(classified)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1), 
    geometry: roi, 
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels : 1e12
  }).get('groups')
```

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the code you include, but you haven't included enough of it to help you. Provide a complete and running script that you boiled down to just replicate your issue. Also, include a  link to the script using`Get Link` button in the code editor, to make it easier to help you. Make sure any used assets are shared.